# iPad Falsely Reports Out of Storage

Tags: ipad, storage, recording

I have a teacher in my school who is trying to use an iPad (new - purchased this year) to record classroom activity using the built-in camera.  The iPad has 32 gigs total, with just about 20 gigs available, according to Settings --> General --> iPad Storage.  However, during the middle of recording a class yesterday the recording stopped and complained that there was no more room available on the iPad.  He looked and saw that there were 20 gigs available, and when we transferred the aborted recording to an iMac to see its size, we found that the recording, such as it was, was only 2.7 Gigs in size.

What gives?

Comment: [See this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7548568)

Comment: And if that doesn't work, back it up locally, wipe it, and restore from the backup. That solves a multitude of issues